# Indentation for Apex Class

Tags: apex

The Issue I am facing is not technical.
I am working on adding a new feature to an already existing class. But Apex Class I am working on does not have proper indentation.

Currently I am doing the  development from the developer console. Is there any way to fix this automatically? Any feature that sets the correct indentation for the whole class? If so that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try using the 'Fix Indentation' option in under the 'Edit' menu in the Developer Console?
[image]

Comment: This option will just add or subtract spaces from selected lines. It is just equal to manual code indentation in my views. Consider using this option when your code has around 100 or more lines and its in total mess. :)

Comment: Although it still doesn't properly support object initialization statements: `new String[]{ 1, 2, 3 };` will cause the indentation of the next like to be messed up. However, it's still far better than having to do it all manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `TextFX` in N++ (screenshot attached). Also there is an interesting [link](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/auto-indentation-plugin-for-notepad)  I found while answering this about code-indentation in N++ but I haven't tried it myself.

[image]

Comment: the might work... but i am not allowed to use freeware in my environment. Quite a headache

Comment: I believe this plugin, I mentioned above, is part of N++. So, its just come with N++. No install/uninstall required.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Eclipse IDE you can install AnyEdits tools and configure it to convert spaces to tabs.

Comment: This answer is really short - could you provide any more details?

Comment: Please use Eclipse update manager to install this plugin.
Eclipse 3.3 - 3.4:
Go to "Help -> Software Updates -> Find and Install... -> Search for new features to install -> Next -> New Remote Site..."

Eclipse 3.5+:
Go to "Help -> Install new Software... -> Work with:"
and use the http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/ as url.


http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/